# Monotouch Google Analytics with app version

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, google-analytics

I'm using the Google Analytics binding (https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/GoogleAnalytics) in my iOS project and everything seems to be working fine except for the app version that is not being tracked. When I see the reports at Google Analytics, the app version is always **(not set)**.

This is the code that I'm using in the app:

```
var ga = GoogleAnalytics.GAI.SharedInstance;
ga.GetTracker("UA-XXXXXXXX-X");
ga.DefaultTracker.TrackView("Home Screen");
```

Is there something that I'm missing to make it track my app version?

Comment: is this all the code including the dll you add in the mobile app and you ca see it tracking in "debug mode" in the simulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to actually set the app version for it to work. I don't know why Google makes you do this:

```
ga.DefaultTracker.AppVersion = NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary[new NSString("CFBundleVersion")].ToString();
```

This will match your version in your Info.plist.

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot. Just a small correction tho: it should be ga.DefaultTracker.AppVersion

Comment: Same concept but without doing the `NSString` stuff yourself: `ga.DefaultTracker.AppVersion = NSBundle.MainBundle.ObjectForInfoDictionary("CFBundleVersion").ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

With the new Google Analytics SDK you need to use the following code

```
[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker.appVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

This will read the app version from your plist file.

Comment: I am not able to get the result with this answer.

Comment: My question was related to Google Analytics for Monotouch. You shared an Objective-C, which doesn't work on Monotouch.